# How to add java typing text

Tags: java, string, list, char

I'm trying to add some text effects to my game by making the text "type"
Here, maybe the pseudocode will make it understandable.

```
String text = "But what I do have are a very particular set of skills, skills I have acquired over a very long career.";

char = characters(text) ///turn string into list/array of letters

i = 0; //initializes i

while (i < text.length) {
    print(char.letter[i]) ///print 'i'th letter in list (starting with 1)

    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100) //wait 1/10th of second

    i++; //repeat for all letters
}
```

**P.S.** comments with triple slashes are things i don't know how to do

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [for-each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) over chars of input text:

```
String text = "...";
for(char c : text.toCharArray()) { 
    System.out.print(c); 
    Thread.sleep(100);  
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Sasha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35242717/1803692) already outlines **how** to do it, to create a really nice-looking typing effect it's important to not always wait the same time between keystrokes.

A human types at different speeds. Usually they have longer pauses before special letters that lie in inconvenient places on the keyboard (think 'z','`' and similar) and makes a longer pause before beginning a new word (or new sentence)

As such you should for the best "typing" experience add a randomization to the sleep-time you have in your game.
Consider the following:

```
String text = "...";
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    // additional sleeping for special characters
    if (specialChars.contains(c)) {
       Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(40) + 15);
    }
    System.out.print(c);
    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(90) + 30);
}
```

These numbers could probably use a little fine-tuning, but that should give you the gist of what's necessary

Comment: Can you expand on the variable 'specialChars' what is it supposed to be equal to?

Comment: `specialChars` is a `Set` containing those Characters that require an additional longer sleep before being typed. Example: `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("z", "\`", "|", "#",...));`