# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method and specialChars cannot be resolved errors

Tags: java, random

So I searched if someone before me wanted to know how a typing text works and found this here [how-to-add-java-typing-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242635/how-to-add-java-typing-text) but the code from Vogel612 gives me errors on "Random.nextInt(40)..." and specialChars.contains...". Btw im a beginner so pls answer like you would answer a beginner xD.

Here is the code I have in my class:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Buildingtext {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String text="bla zzz  ´` asdasdasda y yyyx sdsy sddx";
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        // additional sleeping for special characters
        if (specialChars.contains(c)) {
           Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(40) + 15);
        }
        System.out.print(c);
        Thread.sleep(Random.nextInt(90) + 30);
    }
}
}
```

The "specialChars" error says : **specialChars cannot be resolved.**

Both `Random.nextInt()` errors say : **cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `nextInt(int)` from the type Random.**

I really need help thanks guys D´:

Comment: The snippet assumes you have declared a variable `Random random = new Random();`. As for `specialChars`, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242635/how-to-add-java-typing-text#comment58211530_35244982) beneath the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nextInt is not static method of Random class

> Random c = new Random();
>
> c.nextInt(40);

Answer (score 1):

1- `Random` is the `class` name, and you can not call non-static method using class name, in this case you have to create instance before and use it to call non-static method `nextint`

example :

```
Random random = new Random();// create new object form Random

random .nextInt(40); // call nextint method
```

please read this for more info [/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods)

2- specialChars cannot be resolved, because you are not declared that filed/variable on your code, you have to do something like this.

for example :

```
String specialChars ="!@#$%^&*";
```

and change this condition `if (specialChars.contains(c))` to be  `if (specialChars.contains(String.valueOf(c)))`

Comment: There's no `String.contains(char)` method.

Comment: If you look at the original answer, it was supposed to be a `Set`.